# Apache Ignite CEP implementation with large datasets

Tags: complex-event-processing, ignite

We need a CEP engine which can run over large datasets so I had a look over alternatives like FLink, Ignite etc.

When I was on Ignite, I saw that Ignite's querying api is not eligible enough to run over large data. The reason is: that much data can not be stored into cache(insufficient memory size : 2 TB is needed). I have looked at write-through and read-through but the data payload(not key) is not queryable with Predicates(for ex SQLPredicate).

My question is: Am I missing something or is it really like that?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Ignite is an in-memory system by design. Cache store (read-through/write-through) allows storing data on disk, but queries only work over in-memory data.

> that much data can not be stored into cache(insufficient memory size : 2 TB is needed)

Why not? Ignite is a distributed system, it is possible to build a cluster with more than 2TB of combined RAM.

Comment: It is clustered, I know but the lack of memory size comes from financial constraints. I think it is not A good solution like Apache Flink in this condition.